# How can I create textbox to a div on selextbox value change in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please help me I have some code here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Select Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/admin_template/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#developer").change(onSelectChange);

        });

        function onSelectChange(){
            var selected = $("#developer option:selected");
            var output = "";
            if(selected.val() != 0){
                output = "<input style="width:120px" type="text"  name="other_drcname" value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";
            }
            $("#output").html(output);
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h3>Developers</h3>

        <select id="developer">
            <option value="0">Select Developer</option>
            <option value="1">Todd Sharp</option>
            <option value="2">Brian Meloche</option>
            <option value="3">Ray Camden</option>
            <option value="4">Sean Corfield</option>

            <option value="5">Ben Nadel</option>
            <option value="6">Mark Drew</option>
            <option value="7">Rey Bango</option>
            <option value="8">Mark Mandel</option>
            <option value="9">Joe Rinehart</option>
            <option value="10">Dan Vega</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />


        <div id="output">

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

***I want create textbox in `<div id="output">` on selectbox's value change***

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have a problem with this line:

```
output = "<input style="width:120px" type="text"  name="other_drcname" value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";
```

try changing it to:

```
output = "<input style=\"width:120px\" type=\"text\"  name=\"other_drcname\" value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";
```

You have to escape quotes or use single-quotes (apostrophes)

Comment: @Sardor... no problem... glad you got it working!!!! As a note... it's a good idea to keep with one form of "quoting"... either the escaped quotes or apostrophes (single-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

`output = "<input style="width:120px" type="text"  name="other_drcname" value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";` is wrong. You're quoting it wrong. Try this instead:

`output = "<input style='width:120px' type='text'  name='other_drcname' value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
output = "<input style="width:120px" type="text"  name="other_drcname" value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";
```

should be

```
output = "<input style='width:120px' type='text'  name='other_drcname' value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do this:

output = "< input style='width:120px' type='text'  name='other_drcname' value='"+ selected.text()+"'/>";

Just make sure not to mix up single and double quotes (get rid of the space after the "<" )